# How can I use sys.args[] or getopts to run alignment commands through Python

Tags: python, alignment, bioinformatics, biopython, seq

How would I run a 'MAFFT' alignment through python using sys.args[] or getopts?

I want to automate an alignment through python so that I'm not having to use the standalone command-line MAFFT multiple times for different files. It can get quite time consuming.

Ideally, I would like a function to do this, so that different files could be fed into this for MAFFT alignment.

cheers.

Answer (score 1):

[BioPython has a command line wrapper for the multiple alignment program MAFFT](https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Align.Applications._Mafft.MafftCommandline-class.html):

```
>>> from Bio.Align.Applications import MafftCommandline
>>> mafft_exe = "/opt/local/mafft"
>>> in_file = "../Doc/examples/opuntia.fasta"
>>> mafft_cline = MafftCommandline(mafft_exe, input=in_file)
>>> print(mafft_cline)
/opt/local/mafft ../Doc/examples/opuntia.fasta
```

If the mafft binary is on the path (typically the case on a Unix style operating system) then you don't need to supply the executable location:

```
>>> from Bio.Align.Applications import MafftCommandline
>>> in_file = "../Doc/examples/opuntia.fasta"
>>> mafft_cline = MafftCommandline(input=in_file)
>>> print(mafft_cline)
mafft ../Doc/examples/opuntia.fasta
```

Note that MAFFT will write the alignment to stdout, which you may want to save to a file and then parse, e.g.:

```
stdout, stderr = mafft_cline()
with open("aligned.fasta", "w") as handle:
    handle.write(stdout)
from Bio import AlignIO
align = AlignIO.read("aligned.fasta", "fasta")
```

Alternatively, to parse the output with AlignIO directly you can use StringIO to turn the string into a handle:

```
stdout, stderr = mafft_cline()
from StringIO import StringIO
from Bio import AlignIO
align = AlignIO.read(StringIO(stdout), "fasta")
```

Comment: ApplicationError: Non-zero return code 1 from 'mafft "C:Users\\Mohammed Bilal\\Desktop\\CW1 MB_problem\\BRCA1_mRNA_isolate_D.fasta"', message "'mafft' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"

Comment: @Billy You need to install mafft first

Comment: @Billy And after you have installed MAFFT, change the line `mafft_exe = "/opt/local/mafft"` to point to the location of your mafft executable.

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as solved if it helped you address your issue.